# Linq filter a list of objects based on another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, where-clause

I have a list of Things which each have a List of Countries property:

```
public class Thing
{
  public string Name
  public List<Country> Countries;
}

List<Thing> AllThings;
```

Now I also have a list of countries I'm interested in:

```
List<Country> interestingCountries;
```

How can I find all Things that have all the counties in my interestingCountries list?
For example I have these things:

```
thing1.countries = (NL, BE, FR)
thing2.countries = (NL, BE)
thing3.countries = (FR, BE)
thing4.countries = (NL, BE)
thing5.countries = (NL)
```

And these interesting Countries:

```
interestingCountries = (NL, BE)
```

The result should have these:
thing1, thing2, thing4

I've tried:

```
result = AllThings;
      foreach (var country in interestingCountries )
            result = result.Where(p => p.Countries.Any(c => c == land));
```

This returns all things that have NL or BE as country...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
AllThings.Where(thing => thing.Countries.Intersect(interestingCountries).Count() == interestingCountries.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Contains` and do:

```
var list = AllThings.Where(at => at.Countries.Where(c => interestingCountries.Contains(c.CountryName))).ToList();
```

Comment: This is giving me an error: 'cannot implicitly convert type IEnumerable<Country> to bool' at the second where()

Answer (score 1):

For every `thing` test, if `interestingCountries` contains any element that was not in the `thing.Countries`. (This will return thing1, thing2 and thing4.)

```
AllThings.Where(t => !interestingCountries.Except(t.Countries).Any());
```